# Make fadetoggle fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I make it so jQuery fades in when an element is visible?

Here is my code example:
http://jsfiddle.net/IntelandBacon/nWscz/

```
$('.expand').click(function () {
    $(this).next().css("visibility", "visible");
    $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nyWzK/

Change your JS to look like this

```
$('.expand').click(function () {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

THEN Change `<tr style="visibility: hidden;">` in your css to `<tr style="display:none;">`

if you want to stick with the whole visibility thing then you'll have to explore jquery's `animate` function combined with css `opacity` - HOWEVER, I would recommend against this as its extra effort you don't really need.

- http://api.jquery.com/animate/
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp